# ¿Por qué el código del analizador léxico no produce la salida esperada? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código que implementa un analizador léxico en JavaScript. El objetivo del analizador es leer un código fuente y generar una lista de tokens. Cada token tiene un tipo y un lexema asociado. Sin embargo, cuando ejecuto el código, la salida no coincide con la salida esperada.

Aquí está el código del analizador léxico:

```
// Definir las constantes de los tokens conforme a la tabla de transiciones y el DFA
const TOKEN_INT = 1;
const TOKEN_IF = 2;
const TOKEN_READ = 3;
const TOKEN_FLOAT = 4;
const TOKEN_ELSE = 5;
const TOKEN_WRITE = 6;
const TOKEN_STRING = 7;
const TOKEN_WHILE = 8;
const TOKEN_VOID = 9;
const TOKEN_FOR = 10;
const TOKEN_RETURN = 11;
const TOKEN_ADD = 12;
const TOKEN_SUBTRACT = 13;
const TOKEN_MULTIPLY = 14;
const TOKEN_DIVIDE = 15;
const TOKEN_LESS_THAN = 16;
const TOKEN_LESS_THAN_EQUAL = 17;
const TOKEN_GREATER_THAN = 18;
const TOKEN_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL = 19;
const TOKEN_ASSIGN = 20;
const TOKEN_EQUAL = 21;
const TOKEN_NOT_EQUAL = 22;
const TOKEN_SEMICOLON = 23;
const TOKEN_COMMA = 24;
const TOKEN_OPEN_PAREN = 25;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_PAREN = 26;
const TOKEN_OPEN_BRACKET = 27;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACKET = 28;
const TOKEN_OPEN_BRACE = 29;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACE = 30;
const TOKEN_IDENTIFIER = 31;
const TOKEN_STRING_CONSTANT = 32;
const TOKEN_INTEGER_CONSTANT = 33;
const TOKEN_FLOAT_CONSTANT = 34;

// Definir los estados
const STATE_START = 0;
const STATE_IDENTIFIER = 1;
const STATE_NUMBER = 2;
const STATE_FLOAT = 3;
const STATE_COMMENT = 4;
const STATE_STRING_CONSTANT = 5;
const STATE_ERROR = 6;
const STATE_DONE = 7;

const TRANSITION_TABLE = [
    [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 28, 12, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 0],
    [1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13],
    [40, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 3, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
    [40, 4, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
    [15, 4, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
    [16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
    [18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18],
    [20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
    [40, 40, 40, 40, 22, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
    [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 10, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
    [ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ],
    [ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 24, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ],
    [ 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 25, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 ]
];


// Definir los caracteres de entrada correspondientes a cada columna en la matriz de transición
const DIGITS = '0123456789';
const LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const WHITESPACE = ' \n\t';
const DELIMITERS = WHITESPACE + '+-*/<>=!;,.()[]{}';
const COMMENT_START = '/*';
const COMMENT_END = '*/';


let tokens = [];

function recordToken(tokenType, lexeme, line) {
    // Imprimir el token encontrado en consola o mostrarlo en el navegador
    console.log(`Token encontrado: ${tokenType} - ${lexeme} (linea ${line})`);
    tokens.push({ tokenType, lexeme, line });
}

function lexAn() {
  let state = STATE_START;
  let lexeme = '';
  let line = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < inputCode.length; i++) {
    const inputChar = inputCode[i];

  switch (state) {
    case STATE_START:
      if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_NUMBER;
        lexeme += inputChar;
      } else if (LETTERS.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_IDENTIFIER;
        lexeme += inputChar;
      } else if (inputChar === '/') {
        state = STATE_COMMENT;
      } else if (inputChar === '"') {
        state = STATE_STRING_CONSTANT;
      } else if (DELIMITERS.includes(inputChar)) {
        recordToken(getDelimiterType(inputChar), inputChar, line);
      } else if (inputChar === '') {
        state = STATE_DONE;
      } else if (!WHITESPACE.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_ERROR;
      }
      break;

        case STATE_NUMBER:
          if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else if (inputChar === '.') {
            state = STATE_FLOAT;
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            recordToken(TOKEN_INTEGER_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_FLOAT:
          if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            recordToken(TOKEN_FLOAT_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_IDENTIFIER:
          if (LETTERS.includes(inputChar) || DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            const tokenType = getKeywordType(lexeme);
            recordToken(tokenType, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_COMMENT:
            if (inputChar === '\n' || inputChar === '') {
              state = STATE_START;
              line++;
            } else if (inputChar === '*' && inputCode[i + 1] === '/') {
              state = STATE_START;
              i++; // Skip the '/' character
           }
          break;
  
        case STATE_STRING_CONSTANT:
          if (inputChar === '"') {
            recordToken(TOKEN_STRING_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          } else if (inputChar === '') {
            state = STATE_ERROR;
          } else {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          }
          break;

      case STATE_ERROR:
        console.log(`Error: Caracter inesperado '${inputChar}' en la línea ${line}`);
        state = STATE_DONE;
        break;
    }
  }
}

// Función para obtener el tipo de delimitador
function getDelimiterType(char) {
    switch (char) {
      case '+':
        return TOKEN_ADD;
      case '-':
        return TOKEN_SUBTRACT;
      case '*':
        return TOKEN_MULTIPLY;
      case '/':
        return TOKEN_DIVIDE;
      case '<':
        return TOKEN_LESS_THAN;
      case '<=':
        return TOKEN_LESS_THAN_EQUAL;
      case '>':
        return TOKEN_GREATER_THAN;
      case '>=':
        return TOKEN_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL;
      case '=':
        return TOKEN_ASSIGN;
      case '==':
        return TOKEN_EQUAL;
      case '!=':
        return TOKEN_NOT_EQUAL;
      case ';':
        return TOKEN_SEMICOLON;
      case ',':
        return TOKEN_COMMA;
      case '(':
        return TOKEN_OPEN_PAREN;
      case ')':
        return TOKEN_CLOSE_PAREN;
      case '[':
        return TOKEN_OPEN_BRACKET;
      case ']':
        return TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACKET;
      case '{':
        return TOKEN_OPEN_BRACE;
      case '}':
        return TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACE;
      default:
        return -1; // Delimitador desconocido
    }
  }  

// Función para obtener el tipo de palabra clave
function getKeywordType(lexeme) {
  switch (lexeme) {
    case 'int':
      return TOKEN_INT;
    case 'if':
      return TOKEN_IF;
    case 'read':
      return TOKEN_READ;
    case 'float':
      return TOKEN_FLOAT;
    case 'else':
      return TOKEN_ELSE;
    case 'write':
      return TOKEN_WRITE;
    case 'string':
      return TOKEN_STRING;
    case 'while':
      return TOKEN_WHILE;
    case 'void':
      return TOKEN_VOID;
    case 'for':
      return TOKEN_FOR;
    case 'return':
      return TOKEN_RETURN;
    default:
      return TOKEN_IDENTIFIER;
  }
}

// Define el código a analizar
const inputCode = `
string s;
float f1;
float f2[10];
int miniloc(float a[], int low, int high){
int i; float y; int k;
k = low;
y = a[low];
i = low + 1;
while (i < high){
if (a[i] < x){
y = a[i];
k = i;
}
i = i + 1;
}
return k;
}/* END of miniloc() */
`;

lexAn();

// Imprimir los tokens por fila
let currentLine = 1;
let tokensByLine = [];
let hasError = false;
let errorToken = null;

for (let i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
  const token = tokens[i];
  if (token.line === currentLine) {
    if (token.lexeme.trim() !== '') { // Ignorar tokens vacíos
      tokensByLine.push(token.tokenType);
      if (token.tokenType === -1) { // Delimitador desconocido, se encontró un error
        hasError = true;
        errorToken = token;
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (tokensByLine.length > 0) { // Mostrar solo si hay tokens en la línea actual
      console.log(`Fila ${currentLine} [${tokensByLine.join(', ')}]`);
      if (hasError) {
        console.log(`Error en la fila ${errorToken.line}: Delimitador desconocido '${errorToken.lexeme}'`);
      }
    }
    currentLine = token.line;
    tokensByLine = [];
    if (token.lexeme.trim() !== '') { // Ignorar tokens vacíos
      tokensByLine.push(token.tokenType);
      if (token.tokenType === -1) { // Delimitador desconocido, se encontró un error
        hasError = true;
        errorToken = token;
      } else {
        hasError = false;
        errorToken = null;
      }
    }
  }
}

// Mostrar los tokens de la última línea, si hay alguno
if (tokensByLine.length > 0) {
  console.log(`Fila ${currentLine} [${tokensByLine.join(', ')}]`);
  if (hasError) {
    console.log(`Error en la fila ${errorToken.line}: Delimitador desconocido '${errorToken.lexeme}'`);
  }
}
```

El código define las constantes de los tokens, los estados y la tabla de transiciones. Luego, hay una función lexAn() que realiza el análisis léxico del código de entrada.

El código de entrada es el siguiente:

```
const inputCode = `
string s
float f1
float f2[10];
int miniloc(float a[], int low, int high){
int i; float y; int k;
k = low;
y = a[low];
i = low + 1;
while (i < high){
if (a[i] < x){
y = a[i];
k = i;
}
i = i + 1;
}
return k;
}/* END of miniloc() */
`;
```

Después de ejecutar el analizador léxico, espero obtener la siguiente salida:

'Fila 1 [7, 23]'

'Fila 2 [4, 23]'

'Fila 3 [4, 27, 28, 23]'
...

Sin embargo, la salida real que obtengo es la siguiente:

'Fila 1 [7]'

No se están detectando todos los tokens y los delimitadores no se están identificando correctamente.

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de que el código del analizador léxico no produzca la salida esperada? ¿Hay algún error en la implementación o en la lógica del código?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda para identificar y solucionar el problema. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Que significa esto `Fila 1 [7, 23]` ?? el 7 creo que es porque es un string y el 23??

Comment: El 23 es punto y coma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes muchos errores, los 2 principales son

1. Las líneas no aumentan, salvo en el caso de los comentarios. Lo que produce que todo se acumule en una sola línea
2. Pasas a estado `STATE_DONE` y no haces nada cuando estas en ese estado

La solución para el primero pasa por hacer un `split("\n")` para separar por líneas y usar 2 `for` uno para las líneas y otro para los caracteres de esa línea

El otro problema se soluciona colocando un nuevo `case` para `STATE_DONE`, que al menos cubra el caso de los delimitadores.

Además de sacar los `line++` que ya no serían necesarios

```js
// Definir las constantes de los tokens conforme a la tabla de transiciones y el DFA
const TOKEN_INT = 1;
const TOKEN_IF = 2;
const TOKEN_READ = 3;
const TOKEN_FLOAT = 4;
const TOKEN_ELSE = 5;
const TOKEN_WRITE = 6;
const TOKEN_STRING = 7;
const TOKEN_WHILE = 8;
const TOKEN_VOID = 9;
const TOKEN_FOR = 10;
const TOKEN_RETURN = 11;
const TOKEN_ADD = 12;
const TOKEN_SUBTRACT = 13;
const TOKEN_MULTIPLY = 14;
const TOKEN_DIVIDE = 15;
const TOKEN_LESS_THAN = 16;
const TOKEN_LESS_THAN_EQUAL = 17;
const TOKEN_GREATER_THAN = 18;
const TOKEN_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL = 19;
const TOKEN_ASSIGN = 20;
const TOKEN_EQUAL = 21;
const TOKEN_NOT_EQUAL = 22;
const TOKEN_SEMICOLON = 23;
const TOKEN_COMMA = 24;
const TOKEN_OPEN_PAREN = 25;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_PAREN = 26;
const TOKEN_OPEN_BRACKET = 27;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACKET = 28;
const TOKEN_OPEN_BRACE = 29;
const TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACE = 30;
const TOKEN_IDENTIFIER = 31;
const TOKEN_STRING_CONSTANT = 32;
const TOKEN_INTEGER_CONSTANT = 33;
const TOKEN_FLOAT_CONSTANT = 34;

// Definir los estados
const STATE_START = 0;
const STATE_IDENTIFIER = 1;
const STATE_NUMBER = 2;
const STATE_FLOAT = 3;
const STATE_COMMENT = 4;
const STATE_STRING_CONSTANT = 5;
const STATE_ERROR = 6;
const STATE_DONE = 7;

const TRANSITION_TABLE = [
    [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 28, 12, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 0],
    [1, 1, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13],
    [40, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 3, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14],
    [40, 4, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
    [15, 4, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15],
    [16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16],
    [18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18],
    [20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
    [40, 40, 40, 40, 22, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40],
    [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 10, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23],
    [ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ],
    [ 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 24, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 ],
    [ 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 25, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 ]
];


// Definir los caracteres de entrada correspondientes a cada columna en la matriz de transición
const DIGITS = '0123456789';
const LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const WHITESPACE = ' \n\t';
const DELIMITERS = WHITESPACE + '+-*/<>=!;,.()[]{}';
const COMMENT_START = '/*';
const COMMENT_END = '*/';


let tokens = [];

function recordToken(tokenType, lexeme, line) {
    // Imprimir el token encontrado en consola o mostrarlo en el navegador
    //console.log(`Token encontrado: ${tokenType} - ${lexeme} (linea ${line})`);
    tokens.push({ tokenType, lexeme, line });
}

function lexAn() {
  let state = STATE_START;
  let lexeme = '';
  let line = 0;

//hacemos split, para obtener las lineas
let lineas = inputCode.split("\n");
 for(let l of lineas) //recorremos cada linea
 {
   line++; //aumentamos el n° de linea
 
  for (let i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
    const inputChar = l[i];

  switch (state) {
    case STATE_START:
      if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_NUMBER;
        lexeme += inputChar;
      } else if (LETTERS.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_IDENTIFIER;
        lexeme += inputChar;
      } else if (inputChar === '/') {
        state = STATE_COMMENT;
      } else if (inputChar === '"') {
        state = STATE_STRING_CONSTANT;
      } else if (DELIMITERS.includes(inputChar)) {
        recordToken(getDelimiterType(inputChar), inputChar, line);
      } else if (inputChar === '') {
        state = STATE_DONE;
      } else if (!WHITESPACE.includes(inputChar)) {
        state = STATE_ERROR;
      }
      break;
    case STATE_DONE: //nuevo case
       if (DELIMITERS.includes(inputChar)) {
        recordToken(getDelimiterType(inputChar), inputChar, line);
        lexeme=""; //limpiamos
        state = STATE_START; //volvemos al inicio
      }
      break;
        case STATE_NUMBER:
          if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else if (inputChar === '.') {
            state = STATE_FLOAT;
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            recordToken(TOKEN_INTEGER_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_FLOAT:
          if (DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            recordToken(TOKEN_FLOAT_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_IDENTIFIER:
          if (LETTERS.includes(inputChar) || DIGITS.includes(inputChar)) {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          } else {
            const tokenType = getKeywordType(lexeme);
            recordToken(tokenType, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          }
          break;
  
        case STATE_COMMENT:
            if (inputChar === '\n' || inputChar === '') {
              state = STATE_START;
            } else if (inputChar === '*' && inputCode[i + 1] === '/') {
              state = STATE_START;
              i++; // Skip the '/' character
           }
          break;
  
        case STATE_STRING_CONSTANT:
          if (inputChar === '"') {
            recordToken(TOKEN_STRING_CONSTANT, lexeme, line);
            state = STATE_DONE;
            continue;
          } else if (inputChar === '') {
            state = STATE_ERROR;
          } else {
            lexeme += inputChar;
          }
          break;

      case STATE_ERROR:
        console.log(`Error: Caracter inesperado '${inputChar}' en la línea ${line}`);
        state = STATE_DONE;
        break;
    }
  }
}
}

// Función para obtener el tipo de delimitador
function getDelimiterType(char) {
    switch (char) {
      case '+':
        return TOKEN_ADD;
      case '-':
        return TOKEN_SUBTRACT;
      case '*':
        return TOKEN_MULTIPLY;
      case '/':
        return TOKEN_DIVIDE;
      case '<':
        return TOKEN_LESS_THAN;
      case '<=':
        return TOKEN_LESS_THAN_EQUAL;
      case '>':
        return TOKEN_GREATER_THAN;
      case '>=':
        return TOKEN_GREATER_THAN_EQUAL;
      case '=':
        return TOKEN_ASSIGN;
      case '==':
        return TOKEN_EQUAL;
      case '!=':
        return TOKEN_NOT_EQUAL;
      case ';':
        return TOKEN_SEMICOLON;
      case ',':
        return TOKEN_COMMA;
      case '(':
        return TOKEN_OPEN_PAREN;
      case ')':
        return TOKEN_CLOSE_PAREN;
      case '[':
        return TOKEN_OPEN_BRACKET;
      case ']':
        return TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACKET;
      case '{':
        return TOKEN_OPEN_BRACE;
      case '}':
        return TOKEN_CLOSE_BRACE;
      default:
        return -1; // Delimitador desconocido
    }
  }  

// Función para obtener el tipo de palabra clave
function getKeywordType(lexeme) {
  switch (lexeme) {
    case 'int':
      return TOKEN_INT;
    case 'if':
      return TOKEN_IF;
    case 'read':
      return TOKEN_READ;
    case 'float':
      return TOKEN_FLOAT;
    case 'else':
      return TOKEN_ELSE;
    case 'write':
      return TOKEN_WRITE;
    case 'string':
      return TOKEN_STRING;
    case 'while':
      return TOKEN_WHILE;
    case 'void':
      return TOKEN_VOID;
    case 'for':
      return TOKEN_FOR;
    case 'return':
      return TOKEN_RETURN;
    default:
      return TOKEN_IDENTIFIER;
  }
}

// Define el código a analizar
const inputCode = `
string s;
float f1;
float f2[10];
int miniloc(float a[], int low, int high){
int i; float y; int k;
k = low;
y = a[low];
i = low + 1;
while (i < high){
if (a[i] < x){
y = a[i];
k = i;
}
i = i + 1;
}
return k;
}/* END of miniloc() */
`;

lexAn();

//funcion para agrupar
Array.prototype.GroupBy = function (exp) {
    return Object.values(this.reduce((acc, i) => {
        acc[exp(i)] ? acc[exp(i)].push(i) : acc[exp(i)] = [i];
        return acc;
    }, {}));
}
let lineas = tokens
.GroupBy(a=>a.line) //agrupamos por linea
.map(a=> `Fila ${a[0].line} [${a.map(b=>b.tokenType).join(', ')}]`);

console.log(lineas);
```

Obviamente al código le falta más correcciones, pero espero que mi respuesta te encamine a la solución

Comment: Muchas gracias, aplicare lo que me dices, y aparte de lo ya mencionado que correcciones ves necesarias?